# What does slash before a Class name mean

Tags: class, uml, slash

A Class has slash at front and is an Abstract. I have seen derived attributes in class with slash at the beginning but I don't know what does it mean when we have slash before a Class name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robert Harvey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mention of a slash in front of a classifier name in the UML2 spec concerns interfaces of components. In ch. 8.3.1, p. 155:

> Interfaces that are exposed by a Component and notated on a diagram, either
>   directly or through a port definition, may be inherited from a supertype
>   component. These interfaces are indicated on the diagram by preceding the name
>   of the interface by a forward slash.

This seems unlikely to be the case in your example however. So my best guess would be that it's some non-normative use. Apparently some people use a slash to indicate the classifier to be an interface. But again, that's non-normative - the correct presentation would be using the «interface» keyword.

Comment: Thanks. Can you attach the figure 89 in which /orderedItem has been shown to see an example of such interfaces?

Comment: In composite pattern, the Leaf and Composite classes should implement the superclass and the concrete implementation is there in Leaf class so they cannot be interface. Please remove the last paragraph then the answer should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you kind of answered this yourself. A slash in front of an attribute means that the attribute is derived. The value of a derived class is calculated from the value of other base classes in the diagram.

This is sometimes denoted by an operation like `convertToDC():DerivedClass` listed in the object to send information from the base class to the derived class.

Here's a [little more information](http://som.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/reports/themeA/2002/02A47/02A47.pdf) that might help you out.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as you can see, the class called "Data" is base here but still has slash.

Answer (score 0):

A slash in front of a class name is imo not allowed by the UML spec. So this seems to be an error. You should ask the author of the diagram (or tool which created it) about the slash.

(Regarding the derived attributes you are correct. But they are not defined by the superclass but a computation rule.)